# async :false/true difference and use

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code I am dealing with:

```
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://localhost:9090/getPassword",
    data : {
        email : $("#EmailAddress").val()
    },

    success : function(data) {
        var path = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
        if (data == true) {
            toast("Password has been sent on your Email Id", "success");
        } else if (data == false) {

            toast("Sorry , there is no such account", "warning");
        }
    }
})
```

What is the use of `async: false`/`true` in an AJAX call? When should you use it? Does it affect performance if you write a script after the `body` tag instead of writing it in the `head`?

Comment: there is also further question..

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active.

Comment: need more explaination. i have gone through jquery documentation